# Makefile - Manipulation of strings like Bash

Tags: string, bash, makefile

I am trying to extract a file's name from his given path. 
For example, *"folder1/folder2/file.extension"* must give *"file"*

In bash, I would use:

```
file_path=$1
filename="${file##*/}"   # with extension
article_name="${filename%.*}"   # our desired result
```

In a makefile, I got very close after an hour, but it just doesn't work. I am using GNU Make 4.1

This is the last solution I tried:

```
command :=  f=$(file)\; echo '$$$$'"{f\#\#*/}"
result := $(shell $(CMD))
```

By manually giving `file="folder/f.ext"`, I get:
`command = f=folder/f.e; echo $${f##*/}` and 
`result = 5200{f##*/}`

Can you please tell me what should I do to correct this and get the desired result?

Comment: `$(basename $(notdir $(file)))` is probably what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These kind of manipulations are best implemented using the builtin functionality, see [the excellent docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions). In your case:

```
$(basename $(notdir $(yourFileNameVariable)))
```

Comment: Maybe emphasize even more clearly that GNU Make comes with excellent documentation. But +1